# Closure in es6 and this binding

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
// constructor
function IceCream() {
  this.scoops = 0;
}

// adds scoop to ice cream
IceCream.prototype.addScoop = function() {
  const cone = this; // sets `this` to the `cone` variable
  setTimeout(function() {
    cone.scoops++; // references the `cone` variable
    console.log('scoop added!');
  }, 0.5);
};

const dessert = new IceCream();
dessert.addScoop();
console.log(dessert.scoops);
```

In this code my expectation for the output of `console.log(dessert.scoops)`
is to be 1 but it returns 0.

Can anyone give me some valid reason?

Comment: it is give 1 , I just try it ???

Comment: In VS Code. I tried a lot @MuhammadAlbarmawi

Comment: I just copy your code and try it at  chrome console and the result is 1

Comment: But Try in any ide like vs code @MuhammadAlbarmawi

Comment: There is no `console.log(dessert.scoops)` in your code.

Comment: Are you checking it before the timer fires?

Comment: I don't know why this don't gave expected output in any Ide.
I tried in *VS CODE* and *Webstrom*

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` works asynchronously, meaning the contents will be called when your current execution is completed and it moves to the next event in the event loop.

By reading the value *immediately* after calling the method, the closure has not been called yet. You either

1. Have to remove the closure all together and do it synchronously in the `addScoop` function. Or,
2. Ensure you read it after the closure was called. Since you are using es6, promises are available.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise

```
// constructor
function IceCream() {
  this.scoops = 0;
}

// adds scoop to ice cream
IceCream.prototype.addScoop = function() {
  const cone = this; // sets `this` to the `cone` variable
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    cone.scoops++;
    console.log('scoop added!');
    resolve();
  });
};

const dessert = new IceCream();
dessert.addScoop().then(function() {
    console.log(dessert.scoops);
});
```